# nginx alias and wordpress cache

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a nginx server with the following code added to the sites conf file. The first part is an alias to allow the folder called images to be severed when visiting for example: `example.com/images`

The second part has been added to allow permalinks in wordpress to work. Problem is each of the code blocks work separately but not together. The offending line of code is:

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
       }
```

This code stops any files being server from `example.com/images` and shows a 404 error

```
location /images {
    alias /var/www/clients/client0/web6/images;
  }

location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
       }
       # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
       rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
       location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
       }
```

Why does the cache line conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**try_files**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files). This way you can work with settings in another block.

Example url: http://your-site.com/img/lorena_improta.jpg

```
root /var/www/html/stackoverflow;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~* ^/img/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri /48725060/images/$1;
}

location ~* \.(jpe?g|gif|png) {
    expires 1h;
}
```

Comment: alias and try_files have issues from what I know?